# How to use ngrams matching with Solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, nlp, n-gram

I am learning solr. I want to use `ngrams` in Solr. For example:

If a document contains `new york car driver` , that document should not return for the following queries:

```
/select?q=york
/select?q=new
/select?q=new car
```

but it should return for the following queries

```
/select?q=new york
/select?q=car
/select?q=driver
/select?q=car driver
```

( it should consider New York as a single word for better results.There are word sequences that need consider as single word. eg:-New York,Tom Cruise,etc. These words are predefined; all other words should be treated as normal )

How can I achieve this using Solr search?

Comment: So you don't want to use NGrams filter??

Comment: in fact there is no need of n-gram filter..

Comment: new york is an example. what if i have set of words that should always consider a single word like new york

Answer (score 1):

The first try should be put the quotes around the term like "new York" and try.

This would be your second try.

Change the Tokenizer from `StandardTokenizerFactory` to `KeywordTokenizerFactory`.

After the change reindex data and query again.

The third option is use of StrField type which cannot have any tokenization or analysis and will only give results for exact matches.

The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim.

```
 <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

Comment: /select?q="new york" gives results.but how can i achieve the first requirement ?

Comment: whats the first requirement?

Comment: that document should not return for the following queries:

1)  /select?q=york
2 ) /select?q=new

Comment: ok.... the change the tokenizer from from StandardTokenizerFactory to KeywordTokenizerFactory and try...

Comment: strField wont have any tokenziation right ? i think it might not work ( will confirm after checking it) . i have updated the question . could you please check ? thanks

Comment: try by adding this ShingleFilterFactory filter https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory